# Using linked lists with java gui to save conntents of text field in a List

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, linked-list

I have this project I'm trying to do and I would really appreciate any help because I am incredibly stressed out! 
The program should allow someone choose from a range of items, with corresponding prices. They can pick duplicates and as many items as they want. All of this is saved into a linked list and then at the end on the click of a button, the total price plus VAT gets calculated and outputed. This program isn't difficult to create with Java, but my teacher has requetsed it be created with GUI which we haven't been taught. I'm in charge of creating linked list of the items and corresponding 'code access methods', but even with all my research, I just don't know how to apply the Java I know to the GUI. If anyone could help out I would *really* appreciate it.

Comment: Best place to start learning Swing is the [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) trail in the Java Tutorials.

Comment: _I'm in charge of creating linked list of the items and corresponding 'code access methods'_  it seems you are in charge of creating a "model" : a class which contains all the info that the GUI needs and the information that is generated by the GUI (such as the linked list of selected items) as well as the logic the GUI needs (for example sum the items in the linked list).  _code access methods_ are likely getters setters and other methods (add item, remove item, sum etc)  to be used by the GUI when it is created.